# Specify Font type on R Markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

How can I specify a font type i.e `Tahoma` on R Markdown. I am using the following to define my document

```
---
bibliography: bibliography.bib
csl: nature.csl
documentclass: article
fontsize: 12pt
linkcolor: blue
mainfont: Arial
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: Yes

---
```

How can I also specify the font size of figure captions -- like for the figure below

```
![Figure 2: The impact of malaria disease the factors within the bednet that in turn affect infections and other health issues](climate_change.png)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here an example using LaTeX-code. You need a seperate style-file in the same folder of your R markdown file, where you define the font-family.

In the style-file (mystyle.sty) you can define any font from the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/), e.g. Palatino Sans Serif:

```
\usepackage{palatino}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % sans serif
\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont
```

For a way to use Tahoma via LaTeX, please have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165310/is-there-a-way-i-can-use-tahoma-font-from-microsoft-in-latex), or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3101/how-can-i-get-latex-to-use-the-fonts-that-are-already-on-my-pc-via-xetex).

The R markdown file looks like this and you can also use [LaTeX fontsize](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts) commands to change the size of the caption:

```
---
output: 
pdf_document:
    includes:
        in_header: mystyle.sty 
---

\begin{huge}
![Figure 2: the caption of the picture](picture.png)
\end{huge}
```

Comment: I am getting this error when i include the `.sty` file `! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.`

Comment: sorry, I can't reproduce your error. Maybe `.csl` and `.sty` are in conflict, although for me it works with both. Have you checked if Do you have two `\documentclass` -command? You can have a look at the [intermediate Tex](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html) file when you include `keep_tex: true` in the YAML header. Try to trace the origin of the command duplication.

Comment: Great answer - worked for me. I created a new file `mystyle.sty` with `Sublime` and added this one line for Computer Modern font: `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`

Comment: Is there a way to specify the font for the output of a chunk?  I have a table that is nicely formatted by `CreateTableOne` in the `tableone` package, but I would like the font to better match that of the document.